# How can I give user choices and respond to them accordingly, in an outbound call via twilio?

Tags: php, twilio

I have tried to find the solution in their documentation; but all I have found which was most closest to my query was this; https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad-in-php#collect-user-input-with-the-gather-twiml-verb; which was for the calls coming in, not for outbound calls like i need at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you all in advance!

Comment: That works for both outbound and inbound calls. When you make an outbound call, once it connects Twilio will request TwiML in the same way it does for an incoming call. So everything you learned in that guide is applicable to outbound calls too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something to get you started.

*Make a voice call:*
`// page located at http://example.com/make_call.php —>`

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$auth_token = 'your_auth_token';
// In production, these should be environment variables. E.g.:
// $auth_token = $_ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]

// A Twilio number you own with SMS capabilities
$twilio_number = "+15017122661";

// Where to make a voice call (your cell phone?)
$to_number = "+15558675310";

$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$client->account->calls->create(  
    $to_number,
    $twilio_number,
    array(
        "url" => "http://example.com/complex_gather.xml"
    )
);
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/programmable-voice?code-sample=code-make-a-voice-call&code-language=php&code-sdk-version=5.x

---

*Gather input:*
`// page located at http://example.com/complex_gather.xml` (respond with content-type XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Response>
    <Gather action="process_gather.php" method="POST">
        <Say>
            Please enter your account number,
            followed by the pound sign
        </Say>
    </Gather>
    <Say>We didn't receive any input. Goodbye!</Say>
</Response>
```

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/09/hitchhikers-guide-to-twilio-programmable-voice.html

---

*Process digits:*
`// page located at http://example.com/process_gather.php`

```
<?php

    if (empty($_POST["Digits"])) {
        // process digits

    } else {
        // do something

    }

?>
```

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/04/build-a-simple-phone-verification-with-twilio-php-mysql-and-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

I have done this task; i am able to make calls and get choices from user's dialer(DTMF); but I get parse error on the file that i am using to save these user inputs; here is the structure of the twiml object that i am using
Twilio\Twiml Object

```
(
    [element:protected] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Say] => Please enter 1 for yes, 9 for no as we try to verify your identity:
            [Gather] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [numDigits] => 1
                                    [action] => https://accounts.onsitecrm.com/test_twillo/post_script.php?q=1&id=632
                                    [method] => POST
                                )

                            [Say] => Is your full name Ammad Farooqi
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [numDigits] => 1
                                    [action] => https://accounts.onsitecrm.com/test_twillo/post_script.php?q=2&id=632
                                    [method] => POST
                                )

                            [Say] => Are the last 4-digits of your Social Security Number 1234 
                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [numDigits] => 1
                                    [action] => https://accounts.onsitecrm.com/test_twillo/post_script.php?q=3&id=632
                                   [method] => POST
                               )
                            [Say] => Is your Date of Birth 24th of June, 1996?
                       )
                )
        )
)
```

Here is the structure of the file that store's user credentials;

```
$question = (int)$_GET['q'];
$leadid = (int)$_GET['id'];
$input = null;
$get = $_POST['Digits'];    //Digits Pressed

if (array_key_exists('Digits', $_POST)) {
    $x=$_POST['Digits'];
   if($x==1){
       $input = 'YES';
      //do nothing, all good
   }elseif($x==3){
       $input = 'Not Applicable';
       //do nothing
   }elseif($x==9){
       $input = 'NO';
       if($question>8){
           //call enrollment rep
       }
   }else{
       $input = "Not Recognized, Repeat The Question";
   }
}

$data = array();
$data['leadid'] = $leadid;
$data['question'] = $question;
$data['input'] = $input;
$data['get'] = $get;

$fh = fopen('/usr/share/nginx/html/usr_input.1.txt', 'a') or die("Can't open file.");
$results = print_r( $data, true);
fwrite($fh, $results);
fclose($fh);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tblcompcall` WHERE `leadid` = '$leadid'";
$resp = clsdatabase::runQuery($sql);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($resp);
if($num != 0){
    $sql = "UPDATE `tblcompcall` SET `q$question` = '$input' WHERE `leadid` = '$leadid'";
    $result  = clsdatabase::runQuery($sql);
}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tblcompcall` (`leadid`, `q$question`) VALUES ('$leadid', '$input')";
    $result  = clsdatabase::runQuery($sql);
}
```